# How to Add validation rule at the time of insertion but not during Updating field value?

Tags: validation-rule

I want to Add validation rule at the time of insertion but not during Updating field value

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`ISNEW()`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5#ISNEW) function:

> Checks if the formula is running during the creation of a new record and returns TRUE if it is. If an existing record is being updated, this function returns FALSE.

I.E. `AND(ISNEW(),  Name = 'Mike')`. If you have this validation on Account object you cannot create a new Account with Name = `Mike`, but you can change the name of an old one to `Mike`.

Keep in mind that this function is available only in validation rules, field updates, workflow rules, assignment rules, and processes.

Comment: `PRIORVALUE` is another helpful function to determine what's changing, for example if a value is getting set for the first time.